# C# in Depth: Type Constraint

Tags: c#

I was reading C# in Depth and came across this which i can understand:

When it’s constrained to be a reference type, the kind of comparison performed
depends on exactly what the type parameter is constrained to be.

But can't understand this:

If it’s further constrained to derive from a particular type that overloads the == and != operators, those overloads are used.

I will highly appreciate if someone will explain this through example... Plzz

Comment: What about that statement do you not understand?

Comment: consider this example: static bool AreReferencesEqual<T> (T first, T second)
where T : class
{
return first==second;
}

Comment: Make sure you understand type constraints, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx, and operator overloading http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s(v=vs.110).aspx , and then the picture should become clear I suppose.

Comment: in the example above (if T is string) string overloaded operator (==) will not be activated rather it will just compare the references (not the values of the strings as the overloaded == operator of string). What does the author mean by "further constrained to derive from a particular type that overloads the == and != operators, those overloads are used"

Answer (score 3):

`==` and `!=` are the equality and non-equality operators.

These can be overridden by different types - in types that have overridden them, if used as generic type constraints, this implementation will be used for comparisons using these operators.

With your example, that line doesn't apply as you don't have an additional constraint to a type that overrides `==`:

```
static bool AreReferencesEqual<T> (T first, T second) where T : class
{ 
  return first==second; 
}
```

If you had such a type (that was also open to inheritance) then:

If the type that `T` is constrained to does not overload `==`, a simple reference equality test will be done (the default `Object` implementation).

If, however the type does overload `==` (say a business entity where if two instances have the same `id` they are considered identical), that implementation will be used, regardless if you pass in that type or an inheriting type.

Consider an `Person` class that overrides `==`. And a method that is constraining the type parameter to be a `Person`. If you have an `Employee` that derives from `Person` and also overrides `==`, when using `==` in the generic method, the `==` used will be the `Person` one.

Comment: That doesn't sound any clearer than the original statement.  Example, perhaps?

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Fair enough, though it is difficult from the question to tell what the OP doesn't get.

Comment: @ Oded You mean if the T is string then overloaded operator == of string will be used??

Comment: @Sadiq - Yes, that's exactly what I mean.

Comment: @ Oded - But its written in the book: Beware, however—extra overloads that happen to be made available by the type argument specified by the caller are not used.

Comment: @Sadiq - Note that the caveat is in the line you don't get. Only if there is an _additional_ type constraint to such a type, with the overload be used (so if you constrained to `string`, that override would be used, but if you _could_ have a type inheriting from `string` and that also overridden `==` the `string` override would be used).

Comment: @ Oded - which means that: static bool AreReferencesEqual<T> (T first, T second) where T : class { return first==second; } will return false if : Console.WriteLine(AreReferencesEqual(intro1, intro2));             string name = "Jon";
            string intro1 = "My name is " + name;
            string intro2 = "My name is " + name

Comment: @Sadiq - Again, since your class doesn't have an additional constraint to `string` this is not the meaning

Comment: @ Oded - this is not possible:static bool AreReferencesEqual<T>(T first, T second) where T : class, string because string is sealed class

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23453/discussion-between-sadiq-and-oded)

Comment: Oded just told me: Consider a Person class that overrides ==. And that generic method is constraining the type parameter to be a Person( static bool AreReferencesEqual<T>(T first, T second) where T : class, Person). If you have an Employee that derives from Person and also overrides ==, when using == in the generic method, the == used will be the Person one. Thanks a lot Oded

Answer (score 1):

When it's constrained to a reference type without an `operator==` and `operator!=` (the first quote) then the compiler knows it has no knowledge about equality of the type other than use `Object.Equals`--which merely does a reference comparison.

If the constraint is a type that *does* have an `operator==` and `operator!=`, the compiler knows enough that there is something other that `Object.Equals` that it can use for equality and hence uses the type's `operator==` to test for equality (which is usually something other than a reference comparison).